# Can someone help me prove the following proposition?

Tags: induction, recursion

Let S be the set of positive integers defined by

Basis step: 1 ∈ S.

Recursive step: If n ∈ S, then 3n + 2 ∈ S and n^2 ∈ S.

a) Show that if n ∈ S, then n ≡ 1 (mod 4).

b) Show that there exists an integer m ≡ 1 (mod 4) that
does not belong to S.

I do not know how to proceed with this proof and our professor didn't do similar examples in class. Can you please explain me the steps?

Comment: In part a and part b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) This can be done by induction. Clearly, $1\equiv1\pmod4$. And, if $n\equiv1\pmod4$, then:

- $3n+2\equiv3\times1+2\pmod4\equiv1\pmod4$
- if $n=4l+1$, $n^2=16l^2+8l+1\equiv1\pmod4$

b) Take the number $9$. Of course, $9\equiv1\pmod4$. But the first elements of $S$ are $1,5,17,25\ldots$ and so $9\notin S$. And neither is $13$.

Comment: im not sure how you derive 3n+2 congruent to 1(mod 4) and why you choose 4l +1 for n in the second part?

Comment: This is a proof by indection. SO, in both cases, I am assuming that $n\equiv1\pmod4$, which is the same thing as supposing that $n=4l+1$ for some $l$.